# Why am I losing so many observations when I subset? in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> cat = data.frame(decsorgs, age, degree, race, class, marital, region,
+                  relig, sex, srcbelt, born, partyid, WTSSALL)
> dim(cat)
[1] 1129   13
> cat = subset(cat, decsorgs & age & degree & race & class & marital & region &
+                  relig & sex & srcbelt & born & partyid & WTSSALL)
> dim(cat)
[1] 13 13
```

As you can see, my I have 1129 before subsetting and only 13 afterwards. Why is that? I'm trying to make a subset which includes only rows in which `race=0`. Yet, even if I don't set that condition, the mere act of subsetting reduces observations. Please help. I've spent like 3 hours on this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In R, `0` gets converted to `FALSE` when cast with `as.logical`. You want something like:

```
cat <- cat[cat$race == 0, ]
```

Comment: or, using `subset`, `cat = subset(cat, race == 0)`

Comment: I spent 3 hours attempting this. You have are hero. Nay, a god.

Comment: @Hutchins - I'd steer away from using `subset` and use `[` for subsetting tasks.  `subset` can sometimes produce unintended results and is generally not a good function to use when programming.

Comment: However, why is it when I do cat=subset(cat, race==0) it works out, but not when I do cat=subset(cat, race==0 & decsorgs & class....)? What makes adding all the extra variables different?

Comment: @Hutchins see my answer, `descorgs & class` doesn't mean "show me the descorgs and class columns", it does something different

Answer (score 3):

To explain what's actually happening with your original attempt: in R, numbers are treated as "true" if they're nonzero, and "false" when they're 0. `decsorgs & age & degree` tells R to find the rows where all 3 columns are not zero. A simple example:

```
> eg_df = expand.grid(a=0:1, b=0:1, c=0:1)
> eg_df
  a b c
1 0 0 0
2 1 0 0
3 0 1 0
4 1 1 0
5 0 0 1
6 1 0 1
7 0 1 1
8 1 1 1
# Any rows with a 0 value are dropped
> subset(eg_df, a & b & c)
  a b c
8 1 1 1
```

I think what you intended was just to include those columns in your subset, which
is what the `select` argument does:

```
# Drop rows where a or b are 0, include columns b and c:
subset(eg_df, a & b, select=c("b", "c"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what command in your code tells R to remove rows with a 0 value. Like, in subset(eg_df, a & b & c), there is no indication that R should drop rows with 0. Thanks for the help! Does simply listing a variable assume that you want it dropped if it is 0?

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain in the first paragraph. Numbers are treated as "true" if they are nonzero, so `a & b` gets all the rows where `a` and `b` are "true", i.e. nonzero.

Comment: Oh I see. So is it just a default in R to assume you are looking for a variable that meet a TRUE condition?

Comment: @Hutchins It isn't a default in R, it's just the task that the `subset` function was designed to do: keeping or dropping rows depending on a logical condition.